# Why didn't Onkelus change his name upon becoming a Ger?

Tags: names, conversion-to-judaism

When a non-Jew converts to Judaism he/she usually changes their name to a Jewish name, so Why didn't Onkelus change his name upon becoming  a Ger?

Comment: Maybe he did in fact?

Comment: How common is the practice today, that not doing so warrants a reason? How common was it at the time of Onkelus?

Comment: This is a very interesting question about today practice and a question about old practice. An hypothesis: Maybe he was very known with his first name and people continued to call him onkelos.

Comment: Also, why his conversion is always stressed "Onkelos HaGer"? Maybe the two are related?

Comment: Converts to Judaism have a Hebrew name they've picked out for themselves for religious purposes (marriage, synagogue, etc.) but no one is forcing them to use that name every day. Onkelos most likely had a Hebrew name but chose to continue to go by his Greek name, since more people knew him by this name. Perhaps this was intentional, to stress that he was THAT Onkelos, the nephew to the Roman Emperor.

Comment: [Tvunah.org](https://tvunah.org/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%A8/ ) quotes the Maharsham that there is no issur for a convert to remain with his original name, although a change of name is advisable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Rabbi Chaim Kanievsky](http://www.ladaat.info/article.aspx?artid=42990) was asked this question and he said since this was done in order to show that a person that came from the Roman royal family converted.

> ושאלו את מרן שליט"א מדוע אונקלוס הגר לא שינה את שמו, והשיב שמאחר שאין
>   זה הלכה אלא רק מנהג, לכן העדיף אונקלוס להישאר עם שמו, כי היה בכך כבוד
>   שאונקלוס, שהיה מגזע הקיסרות הרומאית, התגייר